# Fatal error: 'stdafx.h' file not found

Tags: c++, c

I am new to programming C++ and am trying to learn myself through websites (learncpp.com) although I am already stuck on compiling my first program =( . They use Visual Studio to program their code and because I am using a macbook, I just use vi and terminal (or should I use something else?)

Here's the helloworld.cpp program I wrote based on the tutorial:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
{
     std::cout <<"Hello World!" <<std::end1;
     return 0;
}
```

when I compiled (gcc -Wall hello.cpp) I get the error :

```
helloworld.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'stdafx.h' file not found

#include "stdafx.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Can anyone give me insight on to how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try, you know, removing the line with the error?

Comment: Remove `#include "stdafx.h"`.

Comment: You don't need that file, just remove it. It's for a `precompiled header` that's specific to Visual Studio, which is a concept you'll cover later on. Welcome to SO!

Comment: yea I did, and I got :helloworld.cpp:4:35: error: no member named 'end1' in namespace 'std'
std::cout <<"Hello World!" <<std::end1;
                             ~~~~~^
1 error generated.

Comment: @self This isn't really a good suggestion for a beginner- if you teach them to remove every line that causes issues, they will end up with a blank document in no time.

Comment: @Jackie Use `endl` (E-N-D-L), not `end1` (E-N-D-one)

Comment: oh, got it, THANK YOU GUYS :D Blah, I'm so bad at this lol

Comment: @BlueIce On the contrary, learning by trial and error is a great way to learn programming, especially if you have time to do so.

Comment: Trial and error might be suitable for Python, but not really for C++. Learning from a good book will save you so much time.

Comment: Your code is C++, not C. If you don't use C language, please don't add C language tag.

Answer (score 14):

1. `stdafx.h` is the precompiled header used by Visual Studio, you do not need this.
2. You seem to have missed out the `int main()` function
3. It is `std::endl` not `std::end1`

So something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
     std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`stdafx.h` is a Precompiled Header file and it is specific to the Visual Studio.
Precompiled Header file is worthless unless you are facing slow compilation Time. In your program, you don't need them at all, so you can remove that and everything will be fine.

You might be guessing if it is not needed then why we include them?

I will Explain it: 
Whenever we add header files (`#include`), The compiler will walk through it, Examine it and then compile the header file whenever CPP file is compiled.

This process is repeated for each and every CPP file that has header file included.

In case if you have 1000 CPP files in a project which has to say xyz.h header file included then the compiler will compile `xyz.h` file 1000 times. it may take a noticeable time.

To avoid that compiler gives us the option to "precompile" the header file so it will get compiled only once to speed up the compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:
a) stdafx.h is not needed (as others noted).
b) 'end1' should be 'endl' (note the letter 'l' vs. the number '1').

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own "precompiled header" by creating a file called `stdafx.h` and placing the following lines within it:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

If you are supplied a project (i.e. from Github) that includes stdafx.h in hundreds of project files but fails to supply it, creating this file may be an alternative to all suggestions given above.